# Customer attribute is not being saved after migration

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, migration, customer-attribute

I have migrate database from Magento 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.2.3 via `data-migration-tool` and it went without any errors in proccess. Everythink I need was mograted to new database. But I have noticed that one of my custom customer attribute is not being saved. Neither in backend or programmatically via repository or facroty.

I've compare it's data in `eav_attribute` and `in customer_eav_attribute` tables with other attributes like firstname which are being saved fine and its similar. `is_system` value is set to false, so it can not be the case.

Is there somethink i'm missing or should I update this attribute? If so then how?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in proccess of migration custom attributes does not get `used_in_forms` value so eventially it ended up that some custom attributes cannot be modified.

After adding new row to `customer_form_attribute` tables with values `adminhtml_customer` and attribute id the problem was fixed.